# cannot enable RTCDataChannel on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc

my chrome version is 26.0.1410.0 canary.   I typed "chrome://flags/" in the browser, and try to find RTCDataChannel. this flag is not on the list.  is this flag removed or I need to get newer version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From version 26, RTCDataChannel runs in Canary without setting a flag. There **was** a flag in version 25.

To test it, try the [simpl.info/dc](http://simpl.info/dc) demo. This only demonstrates communication between 'peers' on the same page, but it's a good place to start.

Comment: This works but for different tabs, I am still getting this error,
"Failed to execute 'send' on 'RTCDataChannel': RTCDataChannel.readyState is not 'open'"
The readyState doesn't move to 'open' from 'connecting'